# Can I use the types of a yarn module with a local module?

Tags: typescript, node-modules, suitescript

So my actual import is `lib/day` but I want to use the types I would get from `dayjs`.
So if I use:

```
import * as day from "dayjs"
```

I get the right types but my code won't compile (it's using the suitescript api so I need to host it locally).
If I use:

```
import * as day from "lib/day"
```

my code works but I don't get types.

Is there a way I can use `lib/day` but have the types I would get from `dayjs`?

I think I might have to use `<reference-path>` but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to do a declaration of Lib/day, or some other file if you wish to keep a specific extension to Lib/day, (for  an "ambient" declaration the extension needs to be .d.ts), and to export it from there.
according to what you wrote, I assumed that you may not be familiar with the concept of "ambient declarations" and I totally recommend you to have a look at the following article:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-ambients-in-typescript/
Don't forget to include your declaration to the "include" array of tsconfig.json